# Problem with recaptchacontrol inside updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, recaptcha

I have a recaptchavalidator, which is inside an updatepanel:

```
        <asp:updatepanel runat=server id=updatepanel1>

    <cc1:recaptchacontrol runat=server publickey=.. privatekey=.. id=recaptchavalidator1/>
<asp:button runat=server id=button1/>
</updatepanel>
```

I am sure that some of you can guess what happens. For those of you who haven't experienced this before, the recaptchacontrol disappears! I have tried redirecting to the same page if the recaptchacontrol returns a false validation, but this has resulted in complex codebehind, and loss of veiwstate.
Is there a simple solution to this? I have looked over some articles on the web, but they seem to be complex and not well structured. I need to change the content of the updatepanel, so keep this in mind.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is what worked for me.  May not be the best solution but worth a shot: http://lakhlaniprashant.blogspot.com/2009/05/recaptchanet-control-in-updatepanel.html

Comment: Scratch that last comment.. it's not a full solution.

Answer (score 4):

I got this to work nicely with just one updatepanel.

```
 <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl Theme="white"  ID="recaptcha" runat="server" PrivateKey="your_pub_key "
                                                    PublicKey="your_pub_key" />

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>

     <asp:Label Visible="false" ID="RecaptchaResult" runat="server" />            
    <asp:Button ID="RecaptchaButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />

    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The key is to have your updatepanel set to conditional around your post button, so that you manually call the update to reload the recaptcha control from the server side.

Then, you call .update() on your panel after you've asked for the reload();

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recaptcha.Validate();

            if (recaptcha.IsValid)
            {
                RecaptchaResult.Text = "Success";

                RecaptchaResult.Text = "You got it!";
                RecaptchaResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                RecaptchaResult.Visible = true;
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "recaptcha", "recaptcha.reload();", true);
                UpdatePanel1.Update();
            }
            else
            {
                RecaptchaResult.Text = this.recaptcha.ErrorMessage;
                RecaptchaResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                RecaptchaResult.Visible = true;
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "recaptcha", "recaptcha.reload();", true);
                UpdatePanel1.Update();

            }

        }
```

Comment: Just a comment, I found that the `recaptcha.reload()` needed to be with an uppercase R i.e. `Recaptcha.reload()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer that I have tried and is working:

[ASP.Net, disappearing Recaptcha, UpdatePanels and Partial PostBacks: Fixed once and for all](http://www.5limes.com.au/blog/?p=55)

Basically it involves creating a hidden div and using jquery to re-render the html.  Also the blog post gives a nice little breakdown of the typical solutions (e.g., using RegisterClientScriptBlock with a simple reload) and why they fail.

```
<div runat="server" id="pbTarget" visible="false"></div>  
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" runat="server" Theme="clean" />
```

code behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
  recaptcha.Validate();  
  if (!Page.IsValid || !recaptcha.IsValid)  
  {  
    pbTarget.Visible = true;  
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(  
      recaptcha,  
      recaptcha.GetType(),  
      "recaptcha",  
      "Recaptcha._init_options(RecaptchaOptions);"  
      + "if ( RecaptchaOptions && \"custom\" == RecaptchaOptions.theme )"  
      + "{"  
      + "  if ( RecaptchaOptions.custom_theme_widget )"  
      + "  {"  
      + "    Recaptcha.widget = Recaptcha.$(RecaptchaOptions.custom_theme_widget);"  
      + "    Recaptcha.challenge_callback();"  
      + "  }"  
      + "} else {"  
      + "  if ( Recaptcha.widget == null || !document.getElementById(\"recaptcha_widget_div\") )"  
      + "  {"  
      + "    jQuery(\"#" + pbTarget.ClientID + "\").html('<div id=\"recaptcha_widget_div\" style=\"display:none\"></div>');"  
      + "    Recaptcha.widget = Recaptcha.$(\"recaptcha_widget_div\");"  
      + "  }"  
      + "  Recaptcha.reload();"  
      + "  Recaptcha.challenge_callback();"  
      + "}",  
      true  
    );  

    return;  
  }  
  else  
  {  
    //normal page processing here...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ContactUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <p>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"
                        CssClass="textbox">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Address</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" 
                        CssClass="textbox"
                        Height="50px"
                        TextMode="MultiLine">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" runat="server"
                                PublicKey="public key"
                                PrivateKey="private key"
                                Theme="white" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" 
                        ChildrenAsTriggers="false" 
                        UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ErrorLabel" runat="server" 
                                EnableViewState="false"
                                ForeColor="Red" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <p>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server"  
                        onclick="SubmitButton_Click" Text="Submit" />
            </p>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.recaptcha.Validate();
        if (recaptcha.IsValid)
        {
            //valid form. post it
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = "Invalid Captcha. Please re-enter the words.";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                this.Page,
                this.Page.GetType(),
                "mykey",
                "Recaptcha.reload();",
                true);
            UpdatePanel2.Update();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null recaptcha.js:110
Recaptcha._set_challenge recaptcha.js:110
Recaptcha.finish_reload recaptcha.js:110
(anonymous function)`